# Start RabbitMQ server failed

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I start my rabbitmq server by command ./rabbitmq-server . 
But on starting broker, it show "BOOT FAILED":

## BOOT FAILED

```
Error description:
function_clause`enter code here`

Stack trace:
[{rabbit_networking,'-boot_tcp/0-lc$^0/1-0-',[5670],[]},
{rabbit_networking,boot_tcp,0,[]},
{rabbit_networking,boot,0,[]},
{rabbit,'-run_boot_step/1-lc$^1/1-1-',1,[]},
{rabbit,run_boot_step,1,[]},
{rabbit,'-start/2-lc$^0/1-0-',1,[]},
{rabbit,start,2,[]},
{application_master,start_it_old,4,
                    [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,272}]}]
```

Comment: Try to use sudo ./rabbitmq-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is incorrect.  The variable `tcp_listeners` in `rabbitmq.config` is set to an integer, `5670`, but it needs to be set to a list of integers, such as `[5670]`.  See [the RabbitMQ configuration guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) for more information.